# Не могу понять как передать TCP сокету флаг TCP_CORC

Tags: linux, c, tcp

Не могу понять как передать TCP сокету флаг TCP_CORC. Не могу найти пример как это сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Включить

```
int state = 1;
setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_CORK, &state, sizeof(state));
```

Выключить

```
int state = 0;
setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_CORK, &state, sizeof(state));
```

fd - это дескриптор сокета

Comment: Главное потом не забыть проверить возвращаемое значение, не то в самый неподходящий момент незаметно подкрадется северный пушной зверь.

Comment: ошибки всегда стоит проверять. Но какой именно здесь может быть зверь?

Comment: Как обычно, кто-нибудь скопипастит код к себе без проверок, а потом даже не узнает, когда код из-за чего-то сработает.

Comment: Эх. Я думал тут история будет интереснее, как с bind...

Comment: о, и уже заминусовали. кто же это мог быть и почему ему в голову пришла такая светлая идея?